# Request Specification is changing Object to String for query params

Tags: java, json, rest, request, rest-assured

In the request specification trying to add query params using the Map<String, Object> but after the request spec gets generated any value in th Object is getting converted to String even if the value passed in Int or anything else

```
 public Response postCall(String body, Map<String, Object> queryParams, int id1, int id2) {
    RequestSpecification requestSpecification = genericRequestBuilder.getRequestSpecificationObject(); // setting the basepath and portno. and login

// The ids can be send via the queryParams map but in both the cases either in map or individual query, the values are getting converted into String

    requestSpecification.queryParams(queryParams);
    requestSpecification.queryParam("id1",id1);
    requestSpecification.queryParam("id2",id2);
    requestSpecification.body(body);
    Response response =
        requestSpecification.post(uri);
    return response;
  }
```

The query parameter changes as noticed in the debug mode:

```
result = {LinkedHashMap@4245}  size = 6
 "stringId1" -> "kmpySmUISimoRrJL6NL73w"
 "stringId2" -> "YOgB1-WjSKyZWoCkuY7kBA"
 "projectIdentifier" -> "1234"
 "requestGuid" -> "1594123919225"
 "id1" -> "1"
 "id2" -> "1"
```

All the fields are string except the id1 and id2

Comment: `Object is getting converted to String` - your code does not show this.

Comment: Oh I missed that. Updating the question

Comment: How is the values being printed out? Maybe it is calling `String.valueOf` ?

Comment: The output of the query string is from Debug mode. This is passed for the request which requires Int as param and the request is failing with 400 as Status code